# JavaScript shake image using getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a tutorial on how to make an image shake when a event happens. It works, However I would like to avoid using the div tag and use the getElementById (since it has a id). I did some googled around and couldn’t find anything on the subject. So it may not be at all possible?

Whenever I do this is doesn’t work.

I changed this

```
 $('#mySubmit input').shake();
```

to this

```
 getElementByid("mySubmit").shake();
```

And the entire script

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st15jap/JppPG/427/)

I’m pretty new to JavaScript, So if this is completely dumb and doesn’t make sense please explain why.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The code you're using for the shake is a jQuery plugin. It requires jQuery to work. You can't use it as it is just by substituting `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an id you can use jQuery id selector, but you in your case 2 elements have the same id that is not valid as ID has to be unique. So assign different ID's to the `div` and `input` button and use the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) like

```js
jQuery.fn.shake = function () {
    this.each(function (i) {
        $(this).css({
            "position": "relative"
        });
        for (var x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: -25
            }, 10).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 50).animate({
                left: 25
            }, 10).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 50);
        }
    });

}

function start() {
    $('#mySubmit').shake();

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySubmitCt" align="center">
    <input type="image" id="mySubmit" src="http://ezelrn.com/session/image/ButtonBlkForward.png">
</div>
<button onclick="start();">test</button>
```

Comment: So with what you are showing I dont need the div at all then right?

Comment: @EzGoing no... if that was the only purpose for the `div` then that is not required

Comment: Awesome Thanks for that help! I tried something similar however i forgot the "#" in  $('#mySubmit').shake();

Answer (score 1):

**Above seems to answer the question, but I also have an alternative approach you might consider using CSS.**

> Visit the website: http://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/ for more
>   information :)

*Happy Coding!*